Deployment slot has empty contents for Azure App Service
I recently set up deployment slots for my apps for Blue/Green deployment.  I created a second slot for a staging environment.  The new deployment slot has it's own URL.  When clicking on this URL, it seems to have no content.
As per documentation from Microsoft (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/deploy-staging-slots?tabs=portal) "The new deployment slot has no content, even if you clone the settings from a different slot".  This seems to be normal behaviour.
Now I am confused, then what is the point of the deployment slot.  Just for pre-configuring parameters?  I know you can have slot specific environment variables.
Would the only way for me to see my updated app be to perform the swap, take a look, and if there's bugs, I would swap back?

Did u select clone from the source slot while creating the slot?

Yes I did, should I change certain settings? As I am testing more, I stopped the containers in the deployment slot, and restarted it, and now it is showing content

Image

If u select do not clone option, an empty slot will be created.

Yup, I originally wanted to see if the content for both my production, and non-production will show the same. But the staging deployment slot URL waas empty.  It appears I just needed to do the classic fix of restarting the deployment slot for data to show up. /facepalm

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

Yes, as mentioned in the MSDoc, the new Deployment slot adds only the configuration settings.

Only the default page will be displayed, Even I got the same.


what is the point of the deployment slot. Just for pre-configuring parameters?


You can deploy new set/different version of code to the created slot.
To test the staging slot, you need to deploy the code to that particular slot.


Would the only way for me to see my updated app be to perform the swap, take a look, and if there's bugs, I would swap back?


If you want to check the same code, select the same code and deploy again to the staging slot.

In Visual Studio you can see the Deployment Slots.




You can see the 2 publish profiles.


Output:

